# почему вместо <h1 style="position: relative;text-align: center;"> для выравнивания текста по центру не использовать просто <center> </center>?

Tags: html, html5

вместо

```
<h1 style="position: relative;text-align: center;">tekst</h1>
```

не использовать бы

```
<center>
   <h1>tekst</h1>
</center>
```

есть какие то подводные камни?

Comment: _"Работа всех [устаревших тегов](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/ustarevshie-tegi-i-atributy) в браузерах еще какое-то время будет поддерживаться как и ранее, однако специалисты рекомендуют постепенно избавляться от таких тегов в старых документах и совсем не использовать в новых для повышения уровня валидности."_

Comment: почему ты решил, что `<center>` нельзя использовать?

Comment: Сопровождать тяжелее. Если надо что бы все заголовки были по центру,  а заказчик сказал - хочу теперь по левому краю, а таких много - пол страницы прийдётся перелопатить. А без <center> в стилях одно исправление и всё.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;` - Это css свойство которое может принимать несколько значений например как `justify`, `left`, `right`.

`<center>` - Это HTML тег не имеющий атрибутов. Данный тег выравнивает содержимое контейнера по центру относительно родительского элемента.

В целом, разницы нету между `text-align: center;` и `<center>`. Это аналоги. Но принято использовать css стили, чем писать инлайн стили в HTML коде.

И допустим если разобрать ваш код, то причисленные вами варианты верные, но с моей точки зрения стоит написать так:

```css
.some-text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="some-text">tekst</h1>
```

Comment: а чем другие варианты "неверные"?

Comment: @Grundy может быть тег center из html4 и в html5 нету его ...

Answer (score 0):

"Использование этого элемента осуждается спецификацией HTML, вместо него применяйте стили" - https://webref.ru/html/center

"Эта функция больше не рекомендуется к использованию. Хотя некоторые браузеры могут по-прежнему поддерживать , возможно, он уже был удален из соответствующих веб-стандартов, либо может быть удален/сохранен только в целях совместимости. Избегайте его использования и, если возможно, обновите существующий код. Имейте в виду, что эта функция может перестать работать в любой момент" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center